# Как сделать фильтр в Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Есть селект в модель которого попадает число 1,2,3,4... 
Есть объект со свойством tags = [2,5] 
Есть вывод этого объекта через ng-repeat, как сделать фильтр который вернет только те элементы которые будут удовлетворять условию выбора из селекта

```
  <li ng-repeat="cat in ourTeamCategories | filter :selectTag">
    <h3>{{cat.title}}</h3>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <b>input: {{catFilter.id}}</b> - - ID: {{cat.id}}
    <p>{{cat.tags}}</p>
  </li>
```

Ссылка
 http://plnkr.co/edit/Yr16nx2kuZR21OTzcwAU?p=preview

Comment: добавьте разметку и контроллеры, которые вы использует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фильтру в ангуляре можно задать конкретное поле по которому фильтровать. В документации к [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) указано, что для этого необходимо передать параметром объект, в котором ключи - это поля по которым будет производится поиск.

конкретно в данном случае нужно заменить

```
filter :selectTag
```

на

```
filter : {'tags':selectTag}
```

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Main', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.title = "Filter Based on Select Value";
      $scope.tags = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'bla'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bla1'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'bla2'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'bla2'
      }];
      $scope.selectTag = 1;
      $scope.ourTeamCategories = [{
        "id": 14,
        "title": 'Management',
        "tags": [1, 2, 3]
      }, {
        "id": 19,
        "title": 'Administration',
        "tags": [2, 3]
      }, {
        "id": 21,
        "title": 'Designers',
        "tags": [4]
      }, {
        "id": 22,
        "title": 'Accounts',
        "tags": [3]
      }, ]
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main">
  <select ng-model="selectTag" ng-options="tag.id as tag.name for tag in tags"></select>
  <div>
    selectTag: {{selectTag}}
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cat in ourTeamCategories | filter :{'tags':selectTag}">
      <h3>{{cat.title}}</h3>
      <!-- for testing -->
      <b>input: {{catFilter.id}}</b> - - ID: {{cat.id}}
      <p>{{cat.tags}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: кстати пробовал так же только без кавычек не работало, хотя такой же фильтр рядом есть только с publish тот работает